# Conversion in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to convert `123456.78` to `123,456.78` in SQL Server?

I am getting the data from a table like `123456.78` and I have to show it as `123,456.78`

Comment: You should do that in presentation layer not in db. It'll be much easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(123456 AS money), 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(123456 AS money), 1) AS varchar)
```

replace 123456  with your number

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(123456.78 AS money), 1) as Value
```